# How to use .net Resource files in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, resource-files

is there anyway i can access my resource files (.resx) in javascript?
if no then are there any workarounds to diplay messages in javascript in different languages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i did it by using Jquery ajax which calls a serverside GetGlobalResourceObject()

Comment: I hope you're not using this to resolve each and every resource.. That's a nice to way to spam your server.

Answer (score 13):

If your javascript is in the page you can use:

```
var globalResource = '<%= Resources.YourClass.YourResourceKey %>';
```

to access the Global Resources (/App_GlobalResources). Or

```
var localResource = '<%= GetLocalResourceObject("LocalResourceKey").ToString() %>';
```

to access the Local resources (/App_LocalResources relative to the page position).

Or a javascript solution may be [this](http://keith-wood.name/localisation.html) nice jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 4):

You can just use double quotes in MVC4.

```
var e = document.getElementById("myelementID");
e.textContent = "@Resource.MyVariable";
```

I tested and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a separate javascript file? You can always use an asp literal to insert text into your html page (for exemple: `var myString = '<asp:literal id="myLiteral" />';`) and fill the literal serverside.